# django customuser matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I think it originates in this view, since it's being transfered to the home view (see below):

```
@login_required
def HomePage(request):
    if request.user.get_profile().phone == "":
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/phone')
    else:
        add_list = add.objects.all()
        ctx = {'last_login':request.session.get('social_auth_login_backend')}
        return render_to_response("homepage.html", {'add_list': add_list, 'ctx':ctx}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And the model:

```
class customuser(models.Model):
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    regdate = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    city = models.ForeignKey(locations, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s user " % self.user

    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            profile, created = customuser.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

    post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)

    class Admin:
        pass
```

Comment: http://dirkgorissen.com/2011/04/18/site-matching-query-does-not-exist-with-djangoappengine-pydev/

Comment: What's the stack trace? Where does this happen? What's the `add` model in `add.objects.all`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of you're problem, but the context dictionary that you're passing to your template looks wrong. The view should probably be re-written -

```
def HomePage(request):
    if request.user.get_profile().phone == "":
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/phone')
    else:
        ctx = {'last_login':request.session.get('social_auth_login_backend'),
               'add_list': add.objects.all()}
        return render(request, "homepage.html", ctx)
```